# Is it possible to specify CSS classes for particular MVC Views?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I overwrite some of the jQuery UI CSS classes in my MVC Views.

I want to move all the style elements to an external style file. But I don't want the overwritten CSS classes to apply to all the views.

Is there a way to specify CSS classes for a particular view, or any recommended way to approach this?

I'd rather keep just one css file if possible.

Comment: Only way you're going to be able to do it is with multiple `.css` files, as far as I know. Unless there's some really clever way I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when you say "classes" you mean "rule-sets":

Since you have added a requirement to stick to one CSS file (and I assume you don't want an inline `<style>` element):

Prefix each selector with an [id selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) and a [descendent combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators): `#someid`

Then add the id to the body element of the view: `<body id="someid">`

Thus:

```
.foo { text-decoration: overline; }
```

becomes

```
#myFirstView .foo { text-decoration: overline; }
```

**Warning**: This will increase the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) of each selector (in the group of rule-sets specific to your view). This could change the order in which these rules and the generic "apply to every page" rules are applied. You could avoid this by prefixing all the shared rules with `#generic` and adding `<html id="generic" lang="en">`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an id to the body of the view you wish to override the styles in.

HTML:

```
<body id="specialview">
  ...
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#specialview .class_override { ... }
```